# "UITextField isNaturallyRTL"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

My iphone app crashes with the following error message:

> 2010-07-26 16:27:30.402 Nav[814:207]
>   *** -[UITextField isNaturallyRTL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x3947fe0 2010-07-26 16:27:30.403
>   Nav[814:207] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '*** -[UITextField isNaturallyRTL]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x3947fe0'

I can't find the text isNaturally RTL in my program. Any ideas on how to find the bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. It was in this line of code:

```
[tempValues setObject:textFieldBeingEdited forKey:tagAsNum];
```

I changed it to the following:

```
[tempValues setObject:textFieldBeingEdited.text forKey:tagAsNum];
```

and that's what fixed it.

Comment: So there's your `UITextField` instead of `NSString` assignment!

Comment: Incidentally, this is why the text-field naming pattern of “nameText”, which I see so frequently in others' questions here on Stack Overflow, is a bad idea.

Comment: hi, where i can find  '[tempValues setObject:textFieldBeingEdited forKey:tagAsNum];????  i tried it in my graph api, but didnt got it. in which its mentioned? plz guide me. Thanks
'

Answer (score 7):

It seems that `isNaturallyRTL` is an (undocumented) `NSString` method. At least `NSString` responds to it.

This may mean that you assign a `UITextField` to some variable, where you should put in an `NSString` instead.

BTW: `0x3947fe0` is the pointer to the `UITextField` that should be an `NSString`, so if you're totally lost, try to find out which `UITextField` has that address (e.g. by a dumb `NSLog("tf X: 0x%x",tfx);`)

Comment: When I try to run that it says that tfx is undeclared.

Comment: you should put in your own `UITextField` variables for `tfx` (I don't know how you named them)

Answer (score 2):

It's because your `UITextField` object is somehow assigned to a variable/property which is not supposed to be a `UITextField`.

It can happen in many different ways.

1. You might have connected the IB outlet incorrectly. Check your nib in the Interface Builder to see your `UITextField` is not connected to something strange.
2. You might have just assigned an `UITextField` to a variable of a different type. In that case, the compiler should have given you a warning. Correct your code and remove all the warnings.
3. You might have not correctly done `retain`/`release`. Do "build and analyze", and remove all warnings.